# Open raster file error: A Debugger is attached to w3wp exe but not configured

Tags: vb.net, iis, arcobjects

I have written a vb.net function to open a raster file. The function is as follows:

```
 Public Function OpenRaster(ByVal directoryName As String, ByVal fileName As String) As IRaster

        Dim workspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory
        Dim rasterWorkspace As IRasterWorkspace
        Dim rasterDataset As IRasterDataset = Nothing

        Try
        workspaceFactory = New RasterWorkspaceFactory
        ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass()

        rasterWorkspace = TryCast(workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(directoryName, 0), IRasterWorkspace)

        rasterDataset = rasterWorkspace.OpenRasterDataset(fileName)
        Catch e As Exception   
        End Try

        Dim pRasterLayer As IRasterLayer = New RasterLayer()
        pRasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(rasterDataset)
        Dim pRaster As IRaster = Nothing
        pRaster = pRasterLayer.Raster
        Return pRaster
    End Function
```

The above function is throwing below error in TryCast statement :

A Debugger is attached to w3wp exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception. To debug this expression detach the current debugger.

I searched on google also, some suggestions were to enable 32-bit in IIS application pool, but enabling this also is not making the code work

Comment: Where you have an empty Catch statement, you are stopping the computer from telling you what went wrong. If you comment out the Try..Catch then you should get an indication of what the actual problem is.

Comment: the control is not even coming in catch block, it is displaying a pop up showing error "A Debugger is attached to w3wp exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception. To debug this expression detach the current debugger."